# Trying to create a tag in svn in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, svn, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the source and destination svn urls in Groovy variables in the scripted Jenkins pipeline. 
On printing both are showing correct values.
I am on windows and I tried to run the svn copy command to create tag

bat 'svn copy ${svnURL} ${tagURL}'

However I got errors..

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@7eb70986
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@7a1e0a2f
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@5a746986
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@593fe377
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@373f7902
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@400c27db
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@740ee2d9
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@740ee2d9
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:569)
```

SVN command line tool is installed on the host machine and typing svn in the command prompt works.

bat 'svn copy %svnURL% %tagURL%' also leads to same error.

**EDIT**

Looks like svn is the naughty keyword here. The variable access is not to blame.
Even

```
bat 'svn help'
```

gave the same error. So I guess the question is how to invoke the svn (installed on host machine) in a pipeline so I could execute a copy to create a tag.